# Synergy Not Launching

Tags: windows-10, synergy

I keep trying to launch Synergy and i keep having the same errors. I don't quite know where to start, when it comes to troubleshooting. I've reinstalled the program a couple times. Here are the logs:

`[2017-02-24T22:00:41] INFO: using last known command: "C:/Program Files/Synergy/synergyc.exe" -f --no-tray --debug INFO --name Cy-Main PC --ipc --enable-drag-drop --profile-dir "C:\Users\IamWo\AppData\Local"
[2017-02-24T22:00:42] INFO: service command updated
[2017-02-24T22:00:42] INFO: starting new process
[2017-02-24T22:00:45] INFO: activeDesktop:Default
[2017-02-24T22:00:45] INFO: starting new process
synergyc.exe: unrecognized option`PC'
Try `synergyc.exe --help' for more information.
[2017-02-24T22:00:49] ERROR: failed to launch, error: process immediately stopped
[2017-02-24T22:00:49] INFO: backing off, wait=2s, failures=1
[2017-02-24T22:00:51] INFO: starting new process
[2017-02-24T22:00:51] INFO: watchdog status: error
[2017-02-24T22:00:53] INFO: activeDesktop:Default
[2017-02-24T22:00:53] INFO: starting new process
synergyc.exe: unrecognized option`PC'
Try `synergyc.exe --help' for more information.
[2017-02-24T22:00:55] ERROR: failed to launch, error: process immediately stopped
[2017-02-24T22:00:55] INFO: backing off, wait=4s, failures=2
[2017-02-24T22:00:59] INFO: starting new process`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be down to there being a space in the screen name. Open up the settings window and change your screen name from `Cy-Main PC` to `Cy-Main-PC` and click on start.

Comment: Thanks yeah, that was partially the problem. I got it fixed for now. However, now clicks randomly stop responding on the client computer. I looked at all the possible workarounds (that i could find, anyway) and they either don't work, or they work for a few clicks and then stop working. It's quite annoying because Synergy didn't always act like this but recently it's been happening more and more. :/